# Access Form Action of another server through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple html form which contain 2 fields and submit button. After hitting submit button my data transfer toward the another server through query string  named   "http://www.123contactform.com" which is load in iframe on my page and the field which is in the iframe become pre-populated with the information coming from query string. That's All I have done.

Now what I want want when the submit button of iframe click, the page transfer towards the another page, I want to restrict that navigation and define my own url with javascript.

Can any one help me, How do I get this???

Regards,
Ammar

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code ?

### And

*Logically What you want is something like this* - You have an iframe on example.com and that iframe load's gmail's login page, You want to change the submit url of `gmail's` login form ?

## NOT POSSIBLE

Comment: Yes, exactly you are right. I want to do the same thing as you said.

Comment: You can not do that as you have no control on iframes having source at other domain.